# A limit of sums of exponentials

Tags: calculus

$$\frac{\sin ^2(1) e^{\frac{1}{x-\sin (1)}}+\sin ^2(2) e^{\frac{1}{x-\sin (2)}}+\sin ^2(3) e^{\frac{1}{x-\sin (3)}}+ ...}{\sin (1) e^{\frac{1}{x-\sin (1)}}+\sin (2) e^{\frac{1}{x-\sin (2)}}+\sin (3) e^{\frac{1}{x-\sin (3)}}+...}=x$$

in the range $x= (0,1)$. The limit converges very slowly.

I suppose Cesaro doesn't apply. Any help is appreciated.

Some member has dragged out the information that this comes from Chapter 7 of Euler, in case anyone is interested. I am sorry for not including this earlier.

Comment: I don't see any question. What is your question?

Comment: I'm sorry, I dont know how to prove this. So I ask how to prove/disprove this. Thanks.

Comment: If you don't know how to prove it, how do you know it's true?

Comment: If you think there is something wrong with my phrasing in terms of the sites rules, I'm sorry. If you are a moderator, you can correct it in appropriate ways. thanks

Comment: Do the series in both numerator and denominator converge? What happens when $x = \sin 1$ or $x = \sin 2$ or $x = \sin 3$?

Comment: Thanks for your meaningful question. It converges to the given value if you take a limit by approaching those values.... The series are not series, they are obviously both divergent. But the expression itself is convergent. That is why I didnt write them as series...You can try to focus on rational values though since they are easier to deal with, I hope.

Comment: I hope I am clear enough...If you take a limit to approach those values that you ask, then the limit converges to the values of those functions, although you cant just insert them there, I guess...

Comment: I repeat my question – how do you know it's true? By the way, if you want to be sure that I see a comment that you mean to address to me, you have to put @Gerry in it.

Comment: @Gerry You know I asked a question first. So you can consider giving me some kind of answer before interrogating me in this way. I dont know who you are but do you think that I would post this here if I thought that it is wrong. Im sorry but why dont you just post a proof/disproof of this stupid tiny thing instead of all the fuss? I mean, if you think it is wrong, you can just forget about it, I hope someone says something. thanks very much for your interest, but your interest is no help to me, and I posted here for help...

Comment: In order to answer a question, it is often helpful to know something more than just the statement of the question. If it came from Chapter 7 of Schmidlap's Complex Analysis text, that's a clue that the material in Chapter 7 of that book might be helpful. If it fell out of some work you're doing on modular forms, that might be helpful to know. If it came from an old Putnam exam, that would be helpful to know. If it's just a conjecture of yours, it's helpful to know how you came to it, and why you believe it. And so on, and so forth.

Comment: @Gerry Thanks. I heard of what modular forms are. It is not a numerical conjecture. I dont know who schmidlap is. But thank you very much for the hint! Sadly, cant just buy a book for the purpose of solving one problem... I have heard of Putnam exams, I am not smart like you guys to solve them easily...  Consider this a conjecture if you want...although I dont and so I think it is worth a proof...  actual hints as to what methods can be used to construct a proof, I would love that. It comes from English machine translation chapter 7 of Eulers introduction to infinite analysis.

Comment: So since I answered you I expect some answer from you too. Sounds fair.

Comment: Fair? I have already helped you by dragging out from you the information that this comes from Chapter 7 of Euler. Indeed, I would recommend that you edit the body of the question to include this information, so no one has to read through all these comments to find where you buried it. Then it will be possible for people to go to the source to see what clues they can find there.

Comment: An English translation of Chapter 7 of Euler can be found at http://www.17centurymaths.com/contents/euler/introductiontoanalysisvolone/ch7vol1.pdf but I don't see anything there that looks like the formula you are asking about. Could you please explain the relation between what's in Euler and what's in your question?

Comment: @Gerry I did what you told me to do. The book is free and online. So it is available. I dont understand. So I am supposed to answer my own question. Maybe it is rude to say this but I had accounts here before and when I asked similar questions I think you have been persistent in this way about some mistakes and deficiencies in my question. Well, it is not perfect but this site is for everyone, am I right? So that is why it is posted here. Am I being singled out for this treatment?

Comment: The point of the relationship is the point of the proof. I cant explain myself very clearly. Not everyone is experienced as you, although I dont know who you are and why so confident you are about what is right and what is wrong.

Comment: You write that the problem comes from Chapter 7 of Euler's book, but when I can't find anything like it in Euler's book, all you have is "the point of the relationship is the point of the proof." You seem to think I'm trying to make life difficult for you, when in fact all I am doing is trying to get you to provide enough information to make it easier for someone to answer your question. I think it would help a potential answerer to know exactly what there is in Euler that led you to write down the formula you are asking about.

Comment: @Gerry Thank you. If that potential answerer is not you, I think the interested person can ask his own questions. If you need something specific that you want to know, you can ask like someone called Paramanand up there did. You know I am supposed to be involved in the information process too, not only the "answerer". There should be interaction not "me,me,me" all the time.